# How do you ContourPlot3D an implicit function of x,y, and z?

Tags: plotting

This is what I am trying to do:

```
ContourPlot3D[4 Log[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] == 1, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}]
```

but all I get is the empty box. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Need to set the correct plot range to see it

```
ContourPlot3D[
 4 Log[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Haha, right on. Thanks!